# How to return the value inside Json

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, json.net

I want to get the data from the server in my Windows phone 7.5 and for that I'm using Json.net .I want to return the returnType value which I received from server but I don't know how to return it.I have tried in many ways but unable to return the correct returnType value.

Please look at my code -

```
public static int getUserRegister(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        int returnType = 0;
      var client = new RestClient(StaticVariables.APIBASEURL + StaticVariables.USERREGISTRATION);

        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);

      request.AddHeader("Authorization", 1 + ";" + appIdKey.AppId + ";" + appIdKey.AppKey);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        request.AddObject(userInfo);

         try
        {
            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                { 

                    var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(response.Content);

                    errorCode = d.ErrorCode;

                    if (errorCode == 13)
                    {
                        returnType =  errorCode;
                        //return errorCode;
                    }

                }
            });
         }
        catch(Exception e)
         {

        }
         return returnType;
}
```

The value of returnType should return 13 in my code but it's returning 0.Please tell me how should i implement this to get correct value of returnType.

Comment: Well, it means the JSON response doesn't match the structure of your `ErrorResponse` object

Comment: No, Actually I'm getting right value in errorCode. But I'm unable to return that value using returnType variable.

Comment: There is no problem with Json.It's working correctly and I'm getting right value but the problem is how to return that value?

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `getUserRegister` from a secondary thread, you can use a mutex to hold the execution of the caller until the value is available:

```
var mutex = new ManualResetEvent(false);

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    try
    {
        // Put your logic here
        returnType =  errorCode;
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.Set();
    }
});

mutex.WaitOne();

return returnType;
```

However, if you're calling `getUserRegister` from the UI thread (for instance, after the user has clicked on a button), then the code will deadlock: the RestClient tries to execute the callback on the UI thread, which you are blocking with the mutex. Therefore, it won't work, and you'll have either to re-think your code or to execute it in a thread.

Edit: To start a thread, let's pretend that your button is calling a "DoSomething" method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Replace it by:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thread = new Thread(DoSomething);
    thread.Start();
}
```

(you may have to add `using System.Threading;` on top of your file)

Then your code will be executed in a background thread, and you will be able to use the mutex as explained above. Two caveats:

- Since your code will be executed in a background thread, the UI will still be responsive. So the user will be able, for instance, to click a second time on the button while your code is still executing. Depending on your needs, you may want to display some kind of progress indicator and prevent some user interactions.
- A UI control cannot be modified from a background thread. If you try to do that, an invalid cross-thread exception will be thrown. To prevent that, use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to update your controls. For instance:

  ```
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.textbox.Text = "Hello world!");
  ```

Comment: @user1928849 and that problem is?

Comment: problem already you mentioned in your answer.Since I'm calling getUserRegister from inside Button, this approach is not working.

Comment: @user1928849 So either start a thread on button press, or rewrite your code to continue the processing in the callback of the ExecuteAsync method

Comment: Sir, Can you suggest any other approach to return the errorCode value?Inside try block I'm changing the returnType value but outside try block returnType is containing older value that i have initialized during declaration.